# nodejs tcp proxy authentication

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, proxy

I am using a nodejs module called `tcp-proxy` to pipe the requests from client to proxy server in order to proxy the requests.

I want this proxy to work only when the user provides the username and password, so I modified my code to make the client send proxy authentication header before proceeding.

Here is my javascript code:

```js
var tcpProxy = require('tcp-proxy');
var server = tcpProxy.createServer({
  target: {
    host: 'HOST'
    port: 'PORT'
  }
});

server.listen(8000);

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    if(!authorized(data, socket)) {
      socket.write('HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required\nProxy-Authenticate: Basic realm=""\nConnection: keep-alive');
      socket.write('\n\r\n');
      socket.end();
    }
  });
});

function authorized(data, socket) {
  if(socket.auth){
    return true;
  }
  for(var i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    if(data.toString().split('\r\n')[i]) {
      var headerType = data.toString().split('\r\n')[i].split(':')[0];
      if(headerType == "Proxy-Authorization") {
        var header = data.toString().split('\r\n')[i].split(':')[1];
        var creds = new Buffer(header.split(' ')[2], 'base64').toString().split(':');
        var username = creds[0];
        var password = creds[1];
        if(username === "USERNAME" && password === "PASSWORD") {
          socket.auth = true;
          return true;  
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Everything is working fine in **Chrome** and **Mozilla Firefox**, but in **Safari** and some other client applications it doesn't work as expected.

I've tried to debug and found that when making `https` request from Safari browser (with proxy set in Wifi settings on Mac) the `Proxy-Authorization` header is missing from the request, and the same happens with the some other client application which have the option to use proxy server.

Since my proxy server is supposed to drop the request if it doesn't find the header it does that for Safari.

Why does this happen? Any solution to get it working on all browsers and applications?

Comment: Have you used the browser dev tools to step through the code and find out where things are failing? No one here is in a position to debug your code.

Comment: @jdv  Yeah, as I mentioned in my question, I tried to debug it and found that safari is not sending the Proxy-Authorization header hence my proxy server is dropping the connection. And I am sorry if I was not clear in my question, I want to know why does safari and some apps don't send the authorization headers while the chrome and Firefox does for https request.

Comment: Wireshark may be best tool to use next at this point.